# Pass a test based on its execution time

Tags: python, pytest

Does `pytest` have something like a timer test?

i.e.

```
@pytest.mark.timer(60)
def test_this_code_runs_in_less_than_x():
    bla()
```

which will fail if `bla` executes for more than 60 seconds?

I can implement this easily with my own decorator, e.g.:

```
import time, threading                                                                                                                                                                                                     
def timeout(func):                                                                                                                                                                                              
    def wrapper():                                                                                                                                                                                              
        start_time = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                
        timeout = start_time + 1                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        th = threading.Thread(target=func)                                                                                                                                                                      
        th.start()                                                                                                                                                                                              
        while time.time() < timeout and th.isAlive():                                                                                                                                                           
            pass                                                                                                                                                                                                
        if th.isAlive():                                                                                                                                                                                        
            raise TimeoutError()                                                                                                                                                                                
        th.join()                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return wrapper                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
@timeout                                                                                                                                                                                                        
def _test():                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    time.sleep(2)                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
def test_should_fail_after_one_second():                                                                                                                                                                        
    _test()
```

but I'm not looking to invent the wheel...

*I know pytest can have a --timeout param, but I'm looking for something to be a part of the test definition, not a configurable parameter that affects ALL tests*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use time elapsed as assertion in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190596/use-time-elapsed-as-assertion-in-unit-tests)

Comment: @DV82XL sadly no - this is what I meant in my _italic comment_

Comment: With [pytest-timeout plugin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-timeout), you can mark individual tests as having a timeout. The notation is almost identical to the one you requested. If you need custom behavior, you'd probably need to implement the decorator yourself.

Comment: @DV82XL - wow, I actually didn't look into the plugin documentation because I already use it - and I missed the decorator part of it entirely :( thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the [pytest-timeout](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/) plugin, you can mark individual tests with a timeout period, measured in seconds:

```py
@pytest.mark.timeout(60)
def test_foo():
    pass
```

You can explicitly choose between the following two "thread methods" by adding a `method` argument to the decorator:

- `thread`: runs a sleep in a separate thread and terminates the test process when the timeout is reached. Beware that this may cause issues with normal JUnit XML output or fixture teardown.
- `signal`: schedules a SIGALRM alarm that cancels the test when the timeout is reached. This allows your test run to complete normally. However, if your code already uses SIGALRM, this may interfere with its normal functionality.

If your system supports [signal.SIGALRM](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGALRM) (typically Unix), the `signal` thread method will be used by default. Otherwise, the `thread` method will be used instead.